# Hibernate Interceptor not working after upgrading to Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor, hibernate-5

Earlier my Interceptor code was working fine for Hibernate 3. After I upgraded to Hibernate 5 and made the necessary changes, callback methods like onSave & onFlushDirty stopped working.

Regarding library changes, below Hibernate 3 jars I replaced with Hibernate 5 jars.

Hibernate 3 jars replaced-

- dom4j.jar
- hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jboss-logging.jar

Hibernate 5 jars added-

- byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar
- classmate-1.3.4.jar
- dom4j-2.1.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar
- javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
- javax.transaction.jar
- jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar

Below is my Interceptor code-

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    System.out.println("onFlushDirty called");
    return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
}

@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    System.out.println("onSavecalled");
    return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}
}
```

If someone can point out what I am missing or any correction that I need to make, it would be very helpful.

> Please Note- Entire Application is working smoothly except that Interceptor Callback methods are not getting called.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are registering the interceptor within your session factory.

Comment: You are right. That part is missing. Strangely, the existing setup is working fine with Hibernate3 jars.
I did some googling & found out different ways of registering Interceptor object.
Can you share a simple code of how to register Hibernate Interceptor with my Session Object? I will try that and update my findings here.

Comment: There is no autoscan kinda thing, so it should be registered somehow ) But in your case if your interceptor is thread-safe just set it on your session factory config and it should start working.

Comment: I would prefer registering my Interceptor with Session instance (everytime I open a new Session) rather than doing it at the Initial Configuration time. Would that be Okay?

Comment: Yes, no difference ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try with the following:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions()
                  .interceptor(new CustomInterceptor())
                  .openSession();
```

Comment: I'm happy it helps.